# How to prevent entry of HTML into ASP.NET Web form text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I have several text boxes in an ASP.NET Web Form. I want to ensure that users are **not** entering HTML into those text boxes. However, I'm not sure how to prevent HTML from being entered. Because of this, I decided that I want to only allow alphanumeric characters, spaces, exclamation point, sharp sign, dollar signs, percentage signs, carets, stars, and left and right parenthesis. I'm omitting the ampersand because I do not want them entering something like "<script&rt;..."

How do I do this? Am I doing it the right way?

Thank you!

Comment: Whatever method you choose, make sure that you validate your input both on the client and the server - client validation can be easily bypassed with a javascript debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx

You can put a blanket statement in the web config ValidateRequest = true will check all user input and throw an error if a user inserts something with bad characters.

If you need to allow some html tags then you will need to roll your own.

Comment: -1: I don't believe throwing errors/exceptions to users is a good practice. And ValidateRequest = true does not cover all forms of XSS prevention, if that is the intention.

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne can you provide some references to ValidateRequest not covering all forms of XSS? I'm curious to read about it. I figured that microsoft would do a better job at catching all cases of dangerous user input better than i/ or the average developer could rolling their own.

Comment: ValidateRequest covers only forms of XSS-preventing that are known at the release of a certain version of (ASP).NET. .Net is not updated regularly on production servers. So if the server runs ASP.NET 2.0 or 3.5 (very common) most modern forms of XSS are unknown thus ignored. So it is a line of defense, but a weak one.

Answer (score 1):

The page will, by default, prevent users from posting HTML or script in textboxes or textareas. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1sw53ds.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I've used:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode();
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method to clean HTML codes from entry like:

```
public static string ClearHTML(string Str, Nullable<int> Character)
{
    string MetinTxtRegex = Regex.Replace(Str, "<(.|\n)+?>", " ");

    string MetinTxtSubStr = string.Empty;

    if (Character.HasValue)
    {
        if (MetinTxtRegex.Length > Character)
        {
            MetinTxtSubStr = MetinTxtRegex.Substring(0, Character.Value);
            MetinTxtSubStr = MetinTxtSubStr.Substring(0, MetinTxtSubStr.LastIndexOf(" ")) + "...";
        }
        else
        {
            MetinTxtSubStr = MetinTxtRegex;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MetinTxtSubStr = MetinTxtRegex;
    }
    return MetinTxtSubStr;
}
```